# How to format the ruby model level errors

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am using mongodb. I implemented some model level validations, and the error message comes in an array format like:

```
{
  "first_name": [
    "is invalid"
  ],
  "last_name": [
    "is invalid"
  ]
}
```

I want to change this to string format like this:

```
{
  "first_name": "is invalid",
  "last_name": "is invalid"
}
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Since I am using grape gem, I could use error_fomatter. I just defined a custom error formatter

```
        (message.each {|k, v|
                      message[k] = v.join(",")
                    }).to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_hash.each{|k, v| your_hash[k] = v.first}
```

Comment: Where do i put this piece of code is what i dont understand